# Unknown function: elm#FindRootDirectory

Tags: vim, elm, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm getting this error message: `Unknown function: elm#FindRootDirectory`
When I open an elm-file within neovim.

I'm using ElmCast/elm-vim as a plugin to write elm code.

I know I could simply remove this plugin but I want to use it.

Also I figured out that I'm not be able to use any commands from ElmCast/elm-vim like `:ElmFormat` for example even if they are suggested in the wildmenu, but the syntax highlighting of this plugin is working.

I've installed the plugin via vim-plug:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/vim-plug-plugins')
        Plug 'elmcast/elm-vim'
call plug#end()
```

I also ran `:PlugUpdate` and `:PlugUpgrade` multiple times.

neovim `CheckHealth` says this:

```
health#deoplete#check
========================================================================
## deoplete.nvim
  - SUCCESS: has("nvim") was successful
  - SUCCESS: has("python3") was successful
  - INFO: If you're still having problems, try the following commands:
    $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log
    $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
    $ nvim
    $ cat /tmp/log_{PID}
    and then create an issue on github

health#nvim#check
========================================================================
## Configuration
  - SUCCESS: no issues found

## Performance
  - SUCCESS: Build type: Release

## Remote Plugins
  - SUCCESS: Up to date

## terminal
  - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=^H
  - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~

## tmux
  - SUCCESS: escape-time: 10ms
  - INFO: $TERM: screen-256color

health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - SUCCESS: Clipboard tool found: xsel

## Python 2 provider (optional)
  - INFO: `g:python_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python2 in the environment.
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python2
  - INFO: Python2 version: 2.7.14
  - INFO: python2-neovim version: 0.1.13
  - SUCCESS: Latest python2-neovim is installed: 0.1.13

## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: `g:python3_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python3 in the environment.
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.2
  - INFO: python3-neovim version: 0.1.13
  - SUCCESS: Latest python3-neovim is installed: 0.1.13

## Ruby provider (optional)
  - INFO: Ruby: ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
  - WARNING: Missing "neovim" gem.
    - SUGGESTIONS:
      - Run in shell: gem install neovim
      - Is the gem bin directory in $PATH? Check `gem environment`.
      - If you are using rvm/rbenv/chruby, try "rehashing".
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the loading order of the plugins is the problem. I'm also using `vim-polyglot`.

When first loading `vim-polyglot` before `elmcast/elm-vim` it results in the mentioned error.

If I first load `elmcast/elm-vim` before `vim-polyglot` it is working like before.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the recommended answer since `vim-polyglot` _includes_ `ElmCast/elm-vim`. If you are using the former, shouldn't you just delete the latter from your `.vimrc`? That's the approach I took, and I haven't noticed any consequences.

Comment: Heads-up: I tried removing elm-vim, per @hkgumbs' suggestion, but it didn't work.

The actions I took included removing elm-vim from vim-plug configs, sourcing configs, running :PlugClean, then reopening the elm file. vim-polyglot isn't particularly helpful either in debugging this. It is probably more correct to lean on vim-polyglot, but the posted answer is a good enough hack for someone who is just dabbling in elm.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't have `autoload/elm.vim` in your runtime path.

How did you install the plugin?

I would recommend you to use something like [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) to handle it.

Comment: I've updated the question to mention that I'm already using vim-plug.